# How to do Logout in Pingfed using Angular

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, pingfederate

I am integration with Pingfed in my Angular Project, I would able to do login and can do token renewal process as well.

But I would not able to access ping_end_session_endpoint **(idp/startSLO.ping)**, I tried with GET and POST methods getting CORS issue. If open this end point in the browser it display message as "Sign Off Successful", but still I can able access **token_endpoint, userinfo_endpoints**.

Is any parameter required?

```
return this.http.get<any>(`https://sso-xxx.com/idp/startSLO.ping`)
    .pipe(
        map(response => {
            return response;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

Comment: I would recommend that you look into the PingFederate [Authentication API](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/elz1592262150859.html). And, unless you're authenticating the user every time, there's no reason to do the SLO - use short-lived access tokens and refresh tokens.

Comment: looks like it a configuration issue, pingfed team fixed it.